# Can not use my own local React library: module.js does not export 'Hello'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, parceljs

I have a local typescript project with a simple React component, Hello:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Hello = () => {
  const [x11, setX11] = useState(0);
  return <div onClick={() => setX11(x11 + 1)}>hello4412!{x11}</div>;
};

export default Hello;
```

In my package.json, I use `parceljs` to build it into dist folder:

```
"main": "dist/main.js",
    "module": "dist/module.js",
    "types": "dist/types.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "parcel build"
    },
```

When I build my project, I get `main.js`, `module.js` and an empty `types.d.ts` file in dist folder. I install this module via yarn: `yarn add  ../../xbase/web/`.

But when I use it like below, I get `@parcel/core: node_modules/xbase/dist/module.js does not export 'Hello'`

```
import { Hello } from "xbase/dist/module";

export const Dashboard = () => {
    return <Hello />;
};
```

Any idea why my exports are not there?

P.S: I also have `"source": "src/index.ts",` in my component's project.

And index.ts is:

```
export * from "./Hello";
```

P.S. 2: My package.json for the main app (removed some irrelevant deps):

```
{
    "source": [
        "src/html/index.html"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "start": "parcel serve src/html/*.html",
        "build": "parcel build --no-cache --no-source-maps",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "parcel": "2.11.0",
        "typescript": "^5.3.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.4",
        "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.13",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
        "xbase": "/Users/mahdi/dev/xbase/web"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which file is `const Hello` in?

Comment: `Hello.tsx` file in the library. I build it to compile them into "dist/*". Then import via yarn add

Comment: "Hello" has the export, but you're trying to import Hello from "module.js"? What's in "module.js"?

Comment: `module.js` is generated via Parcel for me and is in `dist` folder. I think I have to import stuff from `dist` folder. With `import * as Hello from "xbase/Hello";` I get error `@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'xbase/Hello' `

Comment: I think I moved one step further. I added `"type": "module",` to my library's package.json and removed `main` entry there. Now my generated `module.json` looks better. But now when I see the page in browser, I get this error: ```Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app```

Comment: Why are you `yarn add`ing with a relative path?  Add modules at the root app of the project.  The second problem might not be related to the first.  Can you share the contents of your `package.json`?

Comment: React prints a link to debug this issue and (btw none of the suggestions helped) at the end of the page it says this which I think is the culprit: "This problem can also come up when you use npm link or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application folder and one in your library folder. ". I think bunlder might be confusing two reacts, even though I have specified react as a peer dependency in my component.

Comment: Add package.json to the question

Comment: Another discovery: If I `rm -rf project/node_modules/xbase/node_modules` then this works fine and renders fine. So, I'm pretty sure, `node_modules` should not be included in the component I'm importing. But when I `yarn add file://` it, that folder gets copied

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1334

Comment: Ok. At the end I used `yalc` to publish and use my local component. It has been working fine